# HTML Using extends in if statment

Tags: html, templates, haml, extends

I have two different `HTML` layouts. I have created an `if` statement and depending on the circumstance, I would like to extend one of the two `HTML` layouts. I am not sure if this is possible or not. This is what I want to do:

```
- if validlink
    - extends "layouts/successful.html"
- else
    - extends "layouts/unsuccessful.html"
```

Comment: Not sure what you guys are trying to do, questions has already been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's better if you change the perspective. If you design two different **div**, each one with he content of the HTML that you have and then, when you do the **if** statement, you show the one that you need.

EX:

```
if (validlink)
   document.getElementById(ID_OF_DIV).style.visibility="visible";
else
   document.getElementById(ID_OF_DIV).style.visibility="hidden";
```

You can call it with a function or whatever you want. its really easy. It's a function of javascript. HTML/PHP+CSS+JAVASCRIPT is powerful.

Simply and easy in my opinion.

Comment: would you be able to provide an example of how I would go about doing that. Thanks!

Comment: I did an example of how to do the function in JavaScript. You only need to adapt your html code to a **DIV** and then you can show whatever you want.